# Why leaflet marker on click event is not working when using cluster?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, event-propagation

As jsfiddle shows, a single marker can be bound to a on-click event while cluster markers cannot: http://jsfiddle.net/kdnxcwda/

Why, and how to make it work?

My Javascript code:

```
//An extract of address points from the LINZ bulk extract: http://www.linz.govt.nz/survey-titles/landonline-data/landonline-bde
//Should be this data set: http://data.linz.govt.nz/#/layer/779-nz-street-address-electoral/
var addressPoints = [[-37.793167, 175.211862,"the one"],
    [-37.8210922667, 175.2209316333, "2"],
    [-37.8210819833, 175.2213903167, "3"]
    /* many more coordinates, see JSFiddle link */
]; 

var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
}),
    latlng = L.latLng(-37.82, 175.24);

var map = L.map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 13, layers: [tiles]});

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
    var a = addressPoints[i];
    var title = a[2];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {title: title});
    marker.bindPopup(title);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
}

map.addLayer(markers);

$( ".leaflet-marker-pane img").on( "click", function() {
    console.log("click");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen for the `clusterclick` event, check the [documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/tree/leaflet-0.7#events) about events:

```
markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
    console.log('cluster with ' + a.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length + ' markers in it');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q0Lkuzks/

Comment: how can i get the popup content of that single markers?

Comment: @Matoeil You can do it in two ways: `var a = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map).bindPopup('stuff'); console.log(a._popup._content);` (the hacky way) or `var b = L.marker([51.5, -0.095], { someAttribute: 'hello' }).addTo(map).bindPopup("stuff"); console.log(b.options.someAttribute)` (better)